# Easy Distribution Fitting Techniques?

Tags: distributions, fitting

This is a made-up scenario that I am creating, but if I can figure out how to figure out a problem for this scenario, it would help me better understand distribution fitting.

Say you and a friend are fisherman, and your friend likes to exaggerate the truth on the size of the fish they catch. Let's pretend they claim to have caught a certain species of bass 24 inches long from a lake not far from where you live. With some doubt in your friends tale, you want to run a hypothesis test to see if their claim seems plausible.

But the problem is that you don't know the underlying distribution of the length of this certain species of bass for this lake. So you head out to the lake and catch $n$ bass and record their lengths. With this data now acquired, would it be possible to fit the data to a distribution then find the probability of your friends fish's length coming out of this distribution?

I'm aware that certain statistical packages have functions that can help out with this, but I am wondering if all that is necessary. Is there any methods without a computer that could give a relatively good enough estimate of a distribution?

Comment: If you can use Python, I have a GUI statistical distribution fitter at https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/tkinterStatsDistroFit that fits all of the continuous statistical distributions on scipy. If you would prefer to use a web tool, my online statistical distribution fitter is at http://zunzun.com/StatisticalDistributions/1/ that does the same thing. Both are open source.

Comment: "*caught a certain species of bass from a lake that was 24 inches long*" -- that's a very small lake. You would only be able to catch tiny fish in a two-foot long lake, so I think you're probably right to doubt the fish is large.

Comment: Meant the fish was 24 inches long, not the lake. Edited for clarity

Comment: Note that you can estimate quantiles without fitting an assumed distribution; if you catch enough fish and you somehow do it in a way that would reasonably represent a random sample of fish in the lake\*  you could spot that a claim was surprisingly large. $\:$ \* (not sure how you randomly sample fish from a lake, but I guess capture-recapture methods might at least tell you if you're not getting close)

Comment: @Glen No doubt you are familiar with the fish pond in Ankh Morpork: "Ornamental trout lake. 150 yards long, 1 inch wide. Home to one trout, living comfortably provided that it doesn't try to turn around. In fact, the turning around bit involves having a man to do this job on behalf of the fish."   https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Bergholt_Stuttley_Johnson#Landscaping

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, that a lot of statistical toolkits/programs provide functionality to do this distribution estimation. This is mainly, because it is one the main application of statistics -- guessing the underlying distribution. More generally: capture the main and most important features to draw conclusions and make calculations from this that go beyond the initial information.

Your question could actually be a nice real-world example for these lines of thought. But a good answer might be citing several books, or even rewriting them.

You don't need a computer for any of the methods, but it just makes the calculation a lot more tedious. So, rather use the computer. It doesn't get much easier than to use the tools that are already there.

Apart from this, you'd still need to quantify *a relatively good enough estimate*; this is not a well defined term.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess to define a relatively good estimate, are there any "universally accepted" standards? Like how many (at least from textbooks) use an alpha value of $0.05$ when conducting hypothesis testings?

Comment: @ WaveX: Not really. There are two different contexts. The first is the quality of the estimation of the underlying distribution. Even just the description is no longer easy to make. Even more a qualitative measure of "fittingness". The hypothesis testing part is built upon the distribution and the errors of these are in principle unrelated to the error on the distribution. Not in terms of the result, but in terms of the concept.